# GATT support on android phone(4.0 and above)

Tags: android, gatt

Dose GATT profile works on every android phone(4.0 and above) with BLE hardware?

Answer (score 0):

The Gatt central role is available on devices running at least Android 4.3. See [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

The Gatt peripheral role was added with Android 5.0 to the Android SDK.